# It does not fetch the required value Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It does not fetch the required value and writes null What is wrong with the code please help

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("analysis_Client").child(searchUserId);
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                userTotal = ds.child("Total").getValue(String.class);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    };
```

A picture of the firebase of the way to list the data I want to call both(Total - Rest - ProductNum)

[image]

Comment: "writes null" None of the code you shared writes or logs anything, so it's hard to say what's going wrong. Also note that 1) You're not attaching `valueEventListener` to any ref/query in the code you shared, 2) Your `onCancelled` is still ignoring errors despite having a comment that you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Please edit your question and the code that writes that "null" and please also indicate how you attach the listener.